# InvalidCastException even though an explicit cast operator is defined

Tags: c#

It is very strange. My explicit cast operator is not working.

I have a cast operator defined like so:

```
public class OAuthClient
{
  public string LoginUrl { get; set; }
  public string ImagePath { get; set; }
  public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
  public string ImageAlt { get; set; }

  public static OAuthClient FromFrameworkOAuthClient(
              BaseServices.OAuth.IOAuthClient client)
  {
    return new OAuthClient
    {
      LoginUrl = client.LoginUrl,
      ImagePath = client.ImagePath,
      ImageTitle = client.ImageTitle,
      ImageAlt = client.ImageAlt
    };
   }

   public static OAuthClient FromGoogleClient(GoogleClient client)
   {
     return FromFrameworkOAuthClient(client);
   }

   public static OAuthClient FromFacebookClient(FacebookClient client)
   {
     return FromFrameworkOAuthClient(client);
   }

   public static explicit operator OAuthClient(BaseServices.OAuth.FacebookClient client)
   {
     return FromFrameworkOAuthClient(client);
   }

   public static explicit operator OAuthClient(BaseServices.OAuth.GoogleClient client)
   {
     return FromFrameworkOAuthClient(client);
   }
  }
}
```

And then in a `Controller` method, I do this:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<ViewModels.OAuthClient> GetViewModelOAuthClients(
                   IEnumerable<IOAuthClient> oAuthClients)
{
  oAuthClients.ForEach(client => { client.GetLoginUrl(); });

  return oAuthClients.Select(c => (ViewModels.OAuthClient)c);
}
```

Strangely, I get an `InvalidCastException` saying, *Unable to cast object of type 'BaseServices.OAuth.FacebookClient' to type 'Web.Presentation.ViewModels.OAuthClient'.*.

I can't figure out what's going on. This is strange. I am surely missing something very tiny. Help appreciated.

Comment: At what line does the exception fire?

Comment: I've solved it. The exception actually occurred when the iterator/state machine started to execute the foreach loop in the client/View, thereby attempting to execute the `IEnumerable<T>` resulting from the `Select/Transform/Project` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created another, specific explicit cast from `BaseServices.OAuthClient` to `ViewModels.OAuthClient` like so:

```
public static explicit operator OAuthClient(BaseServices.OAuth.OAuthClient client)
{
  return FromFrameworkOAuthClient(client);
}
```

And then cast each item in the `IEnumerable<IOAuthClient>` first to `BaseServices.OAuthClient` and then to `ViewModels.OAuthClient`.

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<ViewModels.OAuthClient> GetViewModelOAuthClients(
                 IEnumerable<IOAuthClient> oAuthClients)
{
  oAuthClients.ForEach(client => { client.GetLoginUrl(); });

  return oAuthClients.Select(c => (ViewModels.OAuthClient)(OAuthClient)c);
}
```

That worked.